# Simple firebase v3 data retrieval with angularfire v2

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

Just started using firebase v3 (released roughly two weeks ago) with angularfire v2 (which according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340023/firebase-angularfire-in-new-firebase/37855952#37855952) fully supports firebase v3). But I am struggling to simply retrieve some data into an angular view.

Here is the controller that simply returns user array and bind it to the view. It breaks on the line using `$firebaseArray` and says: `TypeError: Object expected`

I am using AngularJs 1.5.6. Just to show the versions of firebase and angularfire I am using:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>

(function() {

  var app = angular.module("FirebaseTest");
  var mainCtrl = function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var root = firebase.database().ref();
    var users = root.child('users');
    console.log(users); // this works fine so no problem with firebase connection

    //NOTE: this doesn't work and throws exception
    $scope.users = $firebaseArray(users);
  }

  app.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", mainCtrl]);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", '$firebaseArray', mainCtrl]);
```

This should work

Comment: Don't think that's the problem as it should only affect minifying the file. In fact I think I did try this but it had no effect.

Comment: okej, can you try to use a local firebase.js and angularfire.js ? Just to try out